# Neo4j: How to find all property names for a given node label

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In neo4j, is there a way to get the names of all properties for a given node label.  There are plenty of articles explaining how to do this for a *given node*, but I need to get all property names for *all nodes that belong to a give label*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use a sample of 1000 nodes if you have a big graph, as checking millions and millions of nodes might take time.

```
MATCH (n:Node)
WITH n LIMIT 1000
UNWIND keys(n) as key
RETURN distinct key
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert, but isn't this one way to do it?

```
MATCH(n:Movie)
UNWIND keys(n) AS movie_keys
RETURN DISTINCT movie_keys
```

Answer (score 1):

```
call db.schema.nodeTypeProperties()
```

from https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/procedures/